# Two Shortcodes in one page not working

Tags: shortcode

Here is my code:
when i use two shortcodes at same page only upper short code working.. Second is not working.
Example:- 
if i use these shortcodes `[swt_mm post_id=111] [swt_mm post_id=112]` then only `[swt_mm post_id=111]` working not `[swt_mm post_id=112]

```
<?php

add_shortcode( 'swt_mm', 'swt_mm_shortcode' );

function swt_crypo_shortcode($atts = array(), $content = null, $tag )

{

   shortcode_atts(array(

                                     'post_type'    => 'swt_mm_type',

                                     'post_id'

                                 ), $atts);

                                 /*echo $atts['post_id'];*/


  $chk=get_post_meta($atts['post_id'], 'swt_mm_type', true);

  if($chk=='table')

  {

    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/swt_mm_table.php';

  }else

  if($chk=='tooltip')

  {

    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/swt_mm_tooltip.php';

  }else

  if($chk=='box')

  {

    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/swt_mm_box.php';

  }else


  if($chk=='single-box')

  {

    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/swt_mm_single_box.php';

  }else{

    echo "Shortcode ID is wrong";

  }



}
```

Please help me if there are any mistakes in this code?

Comment: [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Comment: So, Milo I need to replace this?

Comment: Thanx dear Milo its very helpful for me..... thanx a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply replaced 
`require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/swt_mm_single_box.php';`

with

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(__FILE__)); 
include __ROOT__.'/swt_mm_single_box.php';
```

and now its worked for me.
[check Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)